# passing parameter to anonymous function undefined jquery

Tags: jquery, parameters, undefined

I'm having trouble passing a parameter to an anonymous function. Images is an array of filenames. I'm certain that it is defined before I attempt to pass it, and that it is undefined in that anonymous function below. What's the deal? I apologize for any lack of detail. Using jquery 1.9

```
function setup_slideshow(){
$('#slide1').fadeOut(0);
$('#slide0').fadeIn(0);
$.ajax({
    url: "/inc/phplib/fetch_images.php",
    async: true,

    // Receives a string with a colon separated list of filenames (images)
    complete: function(data){
        var images = data.responseText.split(":");
        $('#slide0').attr("src", images[0]);
        $('#slide1').attr("src", images[1]);
        var t = setTimeout(function(images){
            move_slideshow(images, 2, 1);
        }, 550);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
   var images = data.responseText.split(":");
    $('#slide0').attr("src", images[0]);
    $('#slide1').attr("src", images[1]);
    var t = setTimeout(function(){
        move_slideshow(images, 2, 1);
    }, 550);
```

you dont need to pass the images array to setTimeout as its in the higher scope and is accessible inside the setTimeout callback

Comment: I appreciate the help, this was causing issues in other code I had as well.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `// Receives a string with a comma separated list of filenames (images)`

But you used `var images = data.responseText.split(":");` It should be `var images = data.responseText.split(",");`

Full code

```
function setup_slideshow(){
  $('#slide1').fadeOut(0);
  $('#slide0').fadeIn(0);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/inc/phplib/fetch_images.php",
    async: true,

    // Receives a string with a comma separated list of filenames (images)
    success: function(data){
        alert(data); //to check what you get in data
        var images = data.split(":");
        $('#slide0').attr("src", images[0]);
        $('#slide1').attr("src", images[1]);
        var t = setTimeout(function(images){
            move_slideshow(images, 2, 1);
        }, 550);
    }
  });
}
```